# How do I create a transition matrix in Stata (and export it to Excel)?

Tags: stata, matrix

I have data that looks something like this (in Stata):

```
  ID: Cat_period_1:  Cat_period_2:
  1      cat3          cat15
  2      cat35         cat35
  3      cat5          cat6
  ...    ...           ...
  N       N            N
```

I want to create a matrix (and if possible export it into Excel) of transition counts/fractions (i.e. of transitions between `Cat_period_1` and `Cat_period_2`). Any suggestion on how I can do this?

Note: 
I tried to simply do a: `tab Cat_period_1 Cat_period_2`
but doing this returns an error message because the matrix that I want to create is too big for the `tab` command.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reduce the dataset to one of transition frequencies:

```
contract cat_period1 cat_period2, zero
```

except that I have no idea from your question of how you want to hold this in MS Excel.